# How can I make windows in Tkinter that run in succession? (Python 2.7.11)

Tags: python, database, authentication, tkinter

I want to have a login window pop up at first, then once the conditions are satisfied, it *closes* the login window and *opens* a new window.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

#Not really sure what i'm doing here anymore

while True:

    Login = Tk()
    Login.title('Login')
    Login.geometry('400x130')

    NameLabel = Label(Login, text='Username')
    NameLabel.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=100, x=100)

    NameEntryRaw = Entry(Login)
    NameEntryRaw.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=100, x=200)

    CodeLabel = Label(Login, text='Code')
    CodeLabel.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=100, x=100, y=30)

    CodeEntryRaw = Entry(Login)
    CodeEntryRaw.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=100, x=200, y=30)

    def tbd():

        tkMessageBox.showinfo('Congrats!', 'This program is not done yet')

    def login():

        Usernames=list()
        Usernames.append('Mordecai')
        Usernames.append('Ezekiel')
        Usernames.append('Goliath')
        Usernames.append('Abraham')
        Usernames.append('Bartholomew')
        Usernames.append('Jedediah')
        Usernames.append('Solomon')
        Usernames.append('Tobias')
        Usernames.append('Yohanan')
        Usernames.append('Lucifer')

        NameEntry=NameEntryRaw.get()
        CodeEntry=CodeEntryRaw.get()

        CodeReal='116987'

        if Usernames.count(NameEntry) == 0:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('Error!', 'Your Username is invalid! Try Again.')

        else:
            ()

        if CodeEntry != CodeReal:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('Error!', 'The Code entered is invalid! Try Again.')

        else:
            ()     

    LoginButton = Button(Login, text="Login", command=login)
    LoginButton.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=50, width=200, x=100, y=60)
    Login.mainloop()

else:

    DataBase = Tk()
    #this will be the data base
    DataBase.mainloop()
```

Comment: More importantly, I would also like it to be so that IF the  Login window is closed, it terminates the entire script.

Comment: I added that bit in, because it was fairly easy and I'd already written a fair bit of code but SO isn't a code writing service and questions asking for this tend to be received negatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use two `mainloop`'s. Generally speaking, your tkinter app should have a single `.mainloop` called.

As for how to get the login popup and then switch to the window... You can create your root window with the app and when you start your program have a `Toplevel` window be shown with the login stuff, maybe hide / withdraw the root additionally?, have the toplevel have a submit button or something that would validate the credentials. If the credentials are valid, then you can use the `destroy()` method and remove the toplevel widget / go to the root window for your main app.

Having a `while True` repeat the process of creating a GUI + mainloop is bad for obvious reasons.

**Edit**: static is probably a bad term for a mutable object, since it's mutable... Added tuple vs list for global.

You don't need to create a blank list and then use `append` to add your usernames to the `usernames` list. You can make this global. Since, username is a mutable object (it's a list) you could still perform operations elsewhere in your code on this global, say .append etc. Or, if you never have these change i'd make it a tuple, since they're immutable and this "fits" better with the intent.

Instead of using `.count(*)` to get the occurrences of an element in a list you can just use:

```
if (object) in (some list) #Object is an abstraction, not the type
```

If `CodeReal` is static, which it looks to be, you can also make this global.

Here's a quick edit to your code, you can do this without classes, but I used classes here to try to distinctly show the logical separation in the program.

I changed a few variable names as well, so that it was easier to read / understand. I also used `.pack()` and `.grid()` as this was quicker to code than having to use `.place()` everywhere this is an arbitrary choice.

```
import Tkinter as tk 
import tkMessageBox as messagebox
import sys

#No need to do usernames = list() and then .append for each one.
#Just make a global list holding them all...
USERNAMES = ('Mordecai', 'Ezekiel', 'Goliath', 'Abraham', 'Bartholomew',
    'Jedediah', 'Solomon', 'Tobias', 'Yohanan', 'Lucifer')
PASSWORD = '116987' #Was CodeReal, this can be global

#We overrode the closing protocol here.
def closing_protocol():

    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        sys.exit()

#A container for our Login "app".
class Login(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        #We init the toplevel widget.
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #We set the closing protocol to be the overridden version / func.
        self.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closing_protocol)
        tk.Label(self, text='Username').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.username = tk.Entry(self)
        self.username.grid(row=0, column=1)

        tk.Label(self, text='Password').grid(row=1, column=0)
        #Show = '*' just hides the password instead of plain-text like
        #you typically see
        self.password = tk.Entry(self, text='Password', show='*')
        self.password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        #When the button is clicked the _callback function will be called
        tk.Button(self, text='Login', command=self._callback).\
            grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

    def _callback(self):

        #If the username or password is bad, raise an error message.
        if (self.username.get() not in USERNAMES or 
            self.password.get() != PASSWORD):
            messagebox.showerror("Validation Error!", 
                "You have entered invalid credentials.\n" +
                "Please try again.")

        #otherwise, we're good to go. Destroy login / show main app.
        else:
            root.deiconify()
            app.pack()
            self.destroy()

class Main(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="MAIN APP STUFF").pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw() #Hides the root window initially.
    app = Main(root)
    Login()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you for clarifying what you did for me. It proved to be very helpful! Here is what I've settled with. I put the names back and made it to work without classes, as I found it a little too difficult to work with.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox 
import sys
import binascii #Not for this part

Codenames = ['Mordecai', 'Ezekiel', 'Goliath', 'Abraham', 'Bartholomew',
    'Jedediah', 'Solomon', 'Tobias', 'Yohanan', 'Lucifer']

Password = '116987' 

def close_protocol():
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        sys.exit()
#Below for a later part...
def text_to_bits(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    bits = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(text.encode(encoding, errors)), 16))[2:]
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))

def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    n = int(bits, 2)
    return int2bytes(n).decode(encoding, errors)

def int2bytes(i):
    hex_string = '%x' % i
    n = len(hex_string)
    return binascii.unhexlify(hex_string.zfill(n + (n & 1)))
#Above for a later part...
SDB = Tk()
SDB.title("SMEGJALBYT DATA BASE")
SDB.withdraw()

SDBLogin = Toplevel()
SDBLogin.title("Login")

SDBLogin.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_protocol)

CodenameLabel = Label(SDBLogin, text="Codename")
CodenameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

CodenameEntry = Entry(SDBLogin)
CodenameEntry.grid(row=0, column=2)

PasswordLabel = Label(SDBLogin, text="Password")
PasswordLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)

PasswordEntry = Entry(SDBLogin, show='*')
PasswordEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

def login_operation():
    if CodenameEntry.get() not in Codenames:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("INVALID CODENAME!", "Please verify input in the 'Codename' field")

    elif PasswordEntry.get() != Password:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("INVALID PASSWORD!", "Please verify input in   the 'Password' field")

    else:
        SDB.deiconify()
        SDBLogin.destroy()

LoginButton = Button(SDBLogin, text="Login", command=login_operation)
LoginButton.grid(row=2, column=1)
#Code continues...
#Code finisles....
SDB.mainloop()
```

This has the same basic functionality, just organised the way I wanted it.